# How to get more description from Event Viewer error on web server

Tags: asp.net, event-viewer

I have a web application build in asp.net 4.5 which intermittently logs the user out.
I was able to get from the Event Viewer the following error, which I think is the error that's causing the user to be logged out:

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8

Faulting module name: nlssorting.dll, version: 4.0.30319.17929, time stamp: 0x4ffa55e0

Exception code: 0xc00000fd

Fault offset: 0x00001cda

Faulting process id: 0x358c

Faulting application start time: 0x01cf11fdded81940

Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll

Report Id: 4c2ecce0-7df2-11e3-9850-bc764e080abb

I couldn't get much information from the error description, so I would like to see if there is a way to get more information about it, such as what type of exception was thrown by the web application in order to break the process or (ideally) which dll or method threw that error.

Thanks in advance!